# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists or Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Here my migration table

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',50)->unique();
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

when ever i try to migrate the following error occur

*[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
ady exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_incr
ement primary key, `role_id` int unsigned not null, `name` varchar(191) not
 null, `email` varchar(50) not null, `username` varchar(191) not null, `pas
sword` varchar(191) not null, `active` tinyint(1) not null, `remember_token`
 varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp nu
ll) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' alre
ady exists*

**please tell me what should i do ?? i have already use migrate:reset or dumpautoload or rollback nothing happen . lots of time i edit or delete this usersfile and recreated it .**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',50)->unique();
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('active');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: thats problem is solved but still some problem  artisan migrate:reset then this problem happen 
 [ErrorException]
 Undefined index: 2017_05_14_071616_create_users_table

Comment: php artisan migrate and i want to migrate refresh then i used php  artisan migrate:reset

Comment: or refresh also not work , after doing this command this above error happen

Comment: please check this part of documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#running-migrations
you can try use --force flag, like this:

php artisan migrate --force

Comment: lifesaver! even reset was not working gave me "nothing to reset" but this fixed the error. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this problem is showing when you want migrate tables that exist in database :
for this problem just go to PHPMYADMIN manually and drop all table and now 
run command php artisan migrate

Comment: Thanks,It is Working.

Answer (score 1):

***DANGER*** - by dropping a table, rolling back or refreshing your database will destroy all data in that table or database and these methods are not recommended for production use and you should definitely not include drop table behavior in your migration.

It's clear there are a lot of "solutions" for this problem, but all the solutions I read through are very destructive solutions and none of them work for a production database. Yes, they get rid of the error, but at what expense?

Based on the number of solutions, it also seems that there could be several causes to this error.

My error was caused by a missing entry in my migrations table. Which required a very simple solution -- adding the entry back in. A simple issue like this definitely doesn't warrant a database refresh