# Double boot function causes trait collusion

Tags: php, laravel, uuid, laravel-5.8, entrust

The laravel debugger is showing me this error:

Trait method boot has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on App\User

If i remove one of those traits, Uuids or Entrust the error doesn't show. But i need them both. So how can i fix this?'

I am using laravel 5.8

Thanks in advance!

```
namespace App;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use Uuids;
    use EntrustUserTrait;

}
```

trait Uuid

```
   <?php
namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = Uuid::generate(5,'test', Uuid::NS_DNS);
        });
    }
}
```

i think is has to do something with the boot function

Comment: Can you share the definition of these traits?

Comment: Then what about googling that error message? By leaving out the specific method name, I found some hints already

Comment: I don't see any result for: Traid collision between packages laravel

Comment: Can you tell me what you searched for?

Comment: My search string: "because there are collisions with other trait methods on" - this is not a problem of Laravel itself, but of PHP - and it is neither related to the tags `uuid` or `entrust`

Comment: Why is this a problem of php

Comment: With which package? Why do you expect that any random trait from another package is compatible with a trait from your own application?

Comment: I think its something with the boot function

Comment: Well, that's what the error message told you: both traits have a `boot` method, and PHP will only run one of them

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer helped me find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141475/sqlstate42s01-base-table-or-view-already-exists-or-base-table-or-view-already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;

trait Uuids
{
    /**
     * Boot function from laravel.
     */
    protected static function bootUuids()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = (string) Uuid::generate(4);
        });
    }
}
```

reference: [SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists or Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141475/sqlstate42s01-base-table-or-view-already-exists-or-base-table-or-view-already)